# jQuery EasyUI : On page load expand tree

Tags: jquery, ajax, tree, jquery-easyui

I am using the jQuery EasyUI framework. I am using tree base structure. Problem is that i want tree should be opened by default.

its code :

```
var $arbol = jQuery("#arbol-jerarquia-hallazgos");
$arbol.tree({
    url: '../ajax/arbol_estructura.php',
    checkbox: true,
    cascadeCheck: true
});
```

Its comes like this:

[image: This is it]

I want it Like this by default

[image: I want this]

Answer (score 0):

When sending  json data for tree from server side, send ("state":"open") for the parent node. eg.

```
{  
   "text":"Books",  
   "state":"open"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using onLoadSuccess of tree.

```
$arbol.tree({
url: '../ajax/arbol_estructura.php',
checkbox: true,
cascadeCheck: true,
onLoadSuccess: function(node, data)
{
      expandTree();
}
}); 

function expandTree(){

var parent=$arbol.tree('getRoot');

var children=$arbol.tree('getChildren',parent.target);

for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++)
{
    $arbol.tree('expand',children[i].target);
}

}
```